# Cron job works differently than as stand alone

Tags: bash, shell, curl, cron, cat

I have a shell script that periodically checks the ADSL external IP address and send it to my email if it has changed.

```
#! /bin/sh
NEWIP=`/usr/bin/curl ifconfig.me`
OLDIP=`cat ./current`
logger "$NEWIP ...  $OLDIP"
if [ "$NEWIP" != "$OLDIP" ]; then
    TIME=`/bin/date`
    /usr/bin/sendEmail -v -f ip_watcher@xxxoo.com \
    -s smtp.gmail.com:587 -xu ip_watcher@xxxoo.com -xp xxxxxx \
    -t xxx@xxxxx.com \
    -o tls=yes \
    -u "$NEWIP" \
    -m "$NEWIP  $TIME" -a
    /bin/echo "$NEWIP" > ./current
    logger "IP of bjserver1 has changed ..."
else 
     logger "New IP is the SAME with old. not sending ..."
fi
```

this works perfectly when I run it from command line. but after I put it into cron, NEWIP and OLDIP are always the same.  I don't know why , can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `./current`?

You are not using an absolute path in the script, so the file will be wherever it is run. You should use an absolute path.

The only other significant difference between `cron` and a command-line run is the user under whose account the script is executed. Make sure the account (if it's not `root`) has significant privileges to do what you're asking it to do.

Or, better yet, use an established dynamic DNS client so you don't need to be concerned with external hostnames. You do realize you're relying on that web site to be both honest and up, right?

Comment: The differences between interactive and cron are bigger than you assert, and documented in multiple FAQs.

Comment: yes, I know that. it is just a temporary solution for getting us to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: Is there free way of having DDNS ? Looks like all DDNS service provider charge 20$ per year at least.

Comment: @eric dyndns.org used to be free, but now charges. If you don't have a server you could use, I'd recommend http://www.rollernet.us - they're a wonderful email provider that also does DNS (including dynamic DNS). No nonsense, and <$5/month.

Answer (score 2):

At the start of the script you should change directory to the correct one (as a guess). Or use an absolute path.